# Filling listbox from ado query far slower in vb2005 than vb6. Can I speed it up?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, listbox, ado, vb6-migration

I converted some code from vb6 to vb2005 that opens a recordset and populates a listbox
with about 8,000 names. It uses classic ado.

The vb6 code does it in about 0.75 of a second, the first vb2005 code does it in about
5.5 seconds while the second vb2005 code does it in about 4.5 seconds.
Is there any way to improve the vb2005 performance a fair bit more?

```
    //vb6 code

    Dim myconn As ADODB.Connection
    Set myconn = New ADODB.Connection
    myconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Data Source=c:\TestDB1.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=c:\TestDB1.mdw;User ID=TestDB;Password=123456;"
    myconn.Open

    Dim elap As Double
    elap = Timer

    List1.Visible = False
    List1.Clear
    Text1.Text = ""
    Text1.Refresh

    Dim myrec As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim str1 As String
    str1 = "select * from Names"

    myrec.Open str1, myconn

    myrec.MoveFirst

    Do While myrec.EOF <> True
     List1.AddItem myrec.Fields("surname").Value & " " & myrec.Fields("firstname").Value
     myrec.MoveNext
    Loop
    List1.Visible = True
    Text1.Text = Timer - elap
   //
   //
   //vb2005 code '1st attempt 

    Dim myconn As New ADODB.Connection
    myconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Data Source=c:\TestDB1.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=c:\TestDB1.mdw;User ID=TestDB;Password=123456;"
    myconn.Open()
    Dim elap As Double = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds

    list1.Items.Clear()
    Text1.Text = ""
    Text1.Refresh()

    Dim myrec As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim str1 As String = "select * from Names"

    myrec.Open(str1, myconn)

    myrec.MoveFirst()
    list1.BeginUpdate()
    Do While Not myrec.EOF

        list1.Items.Add(myrec.Fields("surname").Value + " " + myrec.Fields("firstname").Value)


        myrec.MoveNext()
    Loop
    list1.EndUpdate()
    Text1.Text = CStr(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds - elap)


   //
   //
   // vb2005 code second attempt


    Dim myconn As New ADODB.Connection
    myconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Data Source=c:\TestDB1.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=c:\TestDB1.mdw;User ID=TestDB;Password=123456;"
    myconn.Open()
    Dim elap As Double = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds

    list1.Items.Clear()
    Text1.Text = ""
    Text1.Refresh()

    Dim myrec As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim str1 As String = "select * from Names"

    myrec.Open(str1, myconn)


    Dim counter As Integer = 0



    myrec.MoveFirst()
    Dim MyList As New List(Of String)
    Dim MyRow As String
    Do While Not myrec.EOF
        MyList.Add(myrec.Fields("surname").Value + " " + myrec.Fields("firstname").Value)
        myrec.MoveNext()
    Loop
    list1.BeginUpdate()
    list1.Items.AddRange(MyList.ToArray)
    list1.EndUpdate()

    Text1.Text = CStr(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds - elap)
```

Comment: Seems like ListBox visibility makes all the difference in the world. Try hiding it in VB.Net sample too.

Comment: Thanks for reading. Yes that ocurred to me too but it doesn't seem to make any difference in vb2005, or at least no appreciable difference

Comment: makes a huge difference in vb6 though.

Comment: One other point of information. I also tried just creating the recordset in each and moving through the entire set without doing any string or listbox work and even then vb6 was about 3 times faster : (

Comment: It looks like you're using classic ADO through .NET interop. It might go faster if you convert it to ADO.NET and cut out the interop layer. (Reader beware - I am just speculating and haven't tried it!)

Comment: It should not change anything performance-wise, but the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods have no use with AddRange, they should only be included when you do multiple Adds. Read the remarks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate.aspx

Comment: MarkJ, I may try that down the line although I've read that in some cases you're better off sticking with ado from a performance standpoint.
Meta-Knight, thanks for that. It didn't seem to affect performance when I removed beginupdate and endupdate as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The original COM based ADO components are not supported for use within .NET use ADO.NET components instead.

BTW, Do your users find having 8000 items to choose from in a List box particulary helpful and easy to use?

Comment: Well they are supported actually or else the thing wouldn't work at all. I'm investigating a migration and as little rewriting of the logic as poss is desirable from a pragmatic pov
Also sometimes users can't be bothered to enter any filtering criteria and then rather than nanny them I give them the full list, after all, it only takes an instant to dish it up.

Comment: It seems ADO in VB.NET doesn't always work, for example see this http://www.vbmigration.com/detknowledgebase.aspx?Id=100 KJack, talking of pragmatism, have you looked at the automatic migration tools from Artinsoft and VBMigration.com?

Comment: Hi MarkJ
Yes I have looked at artinsoft and vbmigration
partner. I have experimented with artinsoft's developer
edition trial and was really impressed.
Some simple programs that used both dao and ado to
interact with access databases converted
flawlessly.
I would say that I will probably ultimately purchase
artinsoft's enterprise edition but in an effort
to learn vb.net and maybe reduce the cost of the conversion
I am looking at doing some of it myself. 
Artinsoft add in design lines in calculating costs
which bumps up the price a bit.

Comment: BTW vbmigration partner add in variable declarations etc.
If you use either artinsoft's or vbmigration partner's assessment tools you'll get a much larger LOC than, say, MZ tools reports. For artinsoft mine was increased by almost 50%.

Comment: BTW (2) Artinsoft's vbuc did a conversion of the above code but added a reference to an artinsoft dll which contains an artinsoft.GUI.helper
class. Consequently the artinsoft conversion worked as fast as vb6.
AFAIK the enterprise edition would result in code that does not require a support library but it's quite a bit dearer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the performance in VB with ADO, but I had a similar issue in Delphi2010 where a query result of 80 000 string values took ages to read into a string list *(Note: absolutely NO visual components connected)*.

Settings like CacheSize etc. did not make any difference (i kept them in case). In the end, even though it does not seem to make sense, i tried using ADODataSet1.DisableControls and ADODataSet1.EnableControls to wrap the while loop in. That worked like a charm.

```
ADODataSet1.DisableControls;
while not ADODataset1.Eof do
begin
  codes.Add(adodataset1Code.Value);
  ADODataset1.Next;
end;
ADODataSet1.EnableControls;
```